# using discord presence.status.equals

Tags: javascript, discord

Trying to find the correct syntax for this...

```
const stat = msg.author.presence.status;     
  if (~msg.author.presence.status.equals("online"))
  {msg.reply(  "\nStatus: " + stat);}
```

// ============

the error from repl.it is....

```
TypeError: msg.author.presence.status.equals is not a function
```

// ======================

the repl is at: 
https://repl.it/@Xiija/nodebot-2b-ish-1

Comment: discord.js docs here... https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Presence

Answer (score 1):

First off, I am trying to understand what the bitwise operator `~` is doing here. According to the documentation linked to, status is a [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String). To compare equality to strings it is recommended to use `===` ([Strict Equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#Strict_equality_using))

Try something like

```
if (msg.author.presence.status === 'online')
```

Comment: works good, ty.. i was trying to figure out how to use their "equals" method, but i'll just go with the easy button :) ... thankx !

Comment: The equals method seems to be for comparing two Presence objects. If they had static instances for online, etc then that might work.